# How to open duplicate sale order for re-new any service after invoice is created in Odoo10

Tags: python-2.7, copy, odoo-10, odoo

I have added a button (Re-new) for product type service in inventory module and invoice is already created for that service. Now I want to Re-new (button) this service for the next 2 years. So, I want to duplicate sale order on that button with full of data. How can I use copy function for this button?

**My Coding structure like below:**

```
@api.one
def dup_line(self)
    self.copy()

<button name="dup_line" type="object" string="Re-New" class="oe_highlight"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
    def dup_line(self):

        res = self.copy()

        return {

            'res_model': 'sale.order',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'res_id': res.id,
            }
```

Comment: can you add some explanation ?

Comment: When you call self.copy, it will create duplicate of sale order and save it as a quotation. So if you want to redirect to the form view of the recently created duplicate sale order, above code is used